# Mesh Curve not exporting properly to unity

Tags: mesh, export, bezier-curves, unity

I tried to export a curve which i turned into a mesh into unity. However the curve appears in an extremely bizzare shape in unity. How do i get unity to import it properly? (P.S. im a complete amatuer)
[image: Here it is in blender]

[image: Here it is in Unity]

Comment: Have you applied rotation before importing in Unity?

Comment: What do you mean by "applying" rotation? How will rotating the model change the export?

Comment: In Object mode select the object and press Ctrl-A / Rotation. If this still happens when you import the file upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ . It is not recommended to import objects with unapplied transformations this can cause a lot of problems.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out i can see the object in unity. i just needed to turn it upside down because the object is invisible from one side. Don't know whats up with that though :/ . Can i give you a +1 or something (im new to stack exchange).

Comment: you could also extrude the mesh 'E' a bit so that it becomes 3D. You could post your own answer. When you have 50rep you will be able to upvote. (I currently don't have the time to post a decent answer)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out my model was 2d so it was invisible from the upper side. I just needed to rotate the model the other way to see the model. There was nothing wrong with the shape of the model. Thanks to stacker for his help.

Comment: Actually the first reson was that you haven't applied scale before exporting the mesh thus modifiers were acting on non-scaled version of model (and as such applying on export). See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data